# How many apps available for android which have option for setting up a proxy authentication

Tags: proxy

I am running Android 2.3.5 on my HTC Explorer phone.And I always connect to internet through my college's wifi which is behind a proxy server and requires basic authentication.Till now i can only connect my browser to the internet,By setting up the proxy server in wifi settings.
I want to know are their other apps available,other than web browsers which have options for proxy settings.Like some online music app,mail checking,some online video viewing app etc.
I dont want to root.

Answer (score 0):

There are many, the prominent ones being [Hotspot Shield](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hotspotshield.android.vpn&hl=en) and [Hideman VPN](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.hideman&hl=en). Hotspot shield works really well so I never tried using any other VPN.